# Alert Dialog Box Leaked Error

Tags: android

I  create one alert box in my android application.But first time it shows correctly.In second or third time it goes to unexpectedly closed,Please help me.

**Log cat error**

```
03-20 05:55:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(4793): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793): Activity com.caprabo.mst.mobpaz.cardapp.activities.OldReceipts has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{418e4990 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-388,198} that was originally added here
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.caprabo.mst.mobpaz.cardapp.activities.OldReceipts has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{418e4990 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-388,198} that was originally added here
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at com.caprabo.mst.mobpaz.cardapp.activities.OldReceipts.alerter(OldReceipts.java:1332)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at com.caprabo.mst.mobpaz.cardapp.activities.OldReceipts$Range_Search_Result.onPostExecute(OldReceipts.java:1256)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at com.caprabo.mst.mobpaz.cardapp.activities.OldReceipts$Range_Search_Result.onPostExecute(OldReceipts.java:1)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 05:55:31.055: E/WindowManager(4793):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

**Code**

```
    private class Search_Result extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Integer>
        {
            String data;
            WebService wsObj;
            CommonFunctions cfObj;
            AlertBox abObj;
            Encryption enObj;
            JSONObject jsObj;
            String result="";
            String encrypted_device_id;
            ProgressDialog dialog;
            int final_flag=0;
            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if(cfObj.isConnectingToInternet())
                {
                    try
                    {               
                        /*jsObj.put("deviceid",encrypted_device_id);
                        jsObj.put("date",extras.getString("date"));*/

                        data=URLEncoder.encode("deviceid","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(encrypted_device_id,"UTF-8");
                        data+="&" + URLEncoder.encode("date","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(extras.getString("date"),"UTF-8");

                        result=wsObj.getWebData(Connector.search_by_date_page, data);
                        System.out.println("date result"+result);
                        if(result==null||result=="")
                        {
                            final_flag=ecObj.server_response_no_response_error;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        final_flag=ecObj.server_response_no_response_error;
                    }
                    if(final_flag!=ecObj.server_response_no_response_error)
                    {
                        publishProgress(getResources().getString(R.string.populating_list));
                        try
                        {
                            if(result!=null && result!="[]"&&result.compareToIgnoreCase("[]")!=0)
                            {                   
                                JSONArray Mainarray=new JSONArray(result);
                                JSONObject obj=Mainarray.getJSONObject(0);
                                int flag=obj.getInt("flag");
                                if(flag==0)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("test6 search");
                                    final_flag=ecObj.no_data_available_code;
                                }
                                else
                                {  
                                    JSONArray jsonArr1=Mainarray.getJSONArray(1);

                                    String date[]=new String[jsonArr1.length()];
                                    String newDate[]=new String[jsonArr1.length()];
                                    String time[]=new String[jsonArr1.length()];                                
                                    String elpoints[]=new String[jsonArr1.length()];                        
                                    String amount[]=new String[jsonArr1.length()];
                                    String transaction_id[]=new String[jsonArr1.length()];
                                    Integer transaction_type[]=new Integer[jsonArr1.length()];
                                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArr1.length();i++)
                                    {
                                        JSONObject json_data=jsonArr1.getJSONObject(i);                     
                                        date[i]=json_data.getString("date");
                                        //calling the function for Date Format
                                        newDate[i]=cfObj.converDateFormate(date[i]);                                                                
                                        time[i]=cfObj.converTimeFormat(date[i]);                                                                                                
                                        elpoints[i]=json_data.getString("earnedpoints");
                                        amount[i]=json_data.getString("amount");
                                        transaction_id[i]=json_data.getString("transactionid");
                                        transaction_type[i]=Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("trantype"));
                                        aldate.add(newDate[i]);
                                        alamount.add(amount[i]);
                                        altransaction_type.add(transaction_type[i]);
                                        if(transaction_type[i]==1)
                                        {
                                            transaction_id[i]="-";
                                        }
                                        altransactionid.add(transaction_id[i]);
                                        key_holder.putString("date"+i,newDate[i]);
                                        key_holder.putString("time"+i,time[i]);
                                        //Only for ccd this needs to be null. For other put the elpoints[i] instead of "-"
                                        key_holder.putString("elpoints"+i,"-");
                                        key_holder.putString("amount"+i,amount[i]);
                                        key_holder.putString("transaction_id"+i,transaction_id[i]);
                                        key_holder.putInt("trantype"+i,transaction_type[i]);
                                    }
                                    final_flag=ecObj.success_code;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("test3 search");
                                final_flag=ecObj.no_data_available_code;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("test4 search");
                            final_flag=ecObj.server_response_error;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    final_flag=ecObj.internet_connectivity_error;
                }
                return final_flag;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                super.onCancelled();
                activity_finisher();
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer rs) {
                super.onPostExecute(rs);
                if(rs==ecObj.success_code)
                {
                    set_up_search_result_display_table();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                else
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if(rs==ecObj.no_data_available_code)
                    {
                        //set_up_search_result_display_table();
                        alerter(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_title),getResources().getString(R.string.no_receipts_date));                
                    }*
    }
    //Alert Box
    public void alerter(String title,String msg)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OldReceipts.this);
            builder.setTitle(title);
            //builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setMessage(msg);

            builder.setPositiveButton(OldReceipts.this.getResources().getString(R.string.Okay),new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    //finish();

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }*
```

Comment: where did you define dialog????. this error occur when you try to show dialog after you've exited an Activity.

Answer (score 2):

It could happen because somewhere somehow you manually close (call ***.close()**  or something like that) your data source object - no matter what it is, it could be HTTP or database connection. Thus, you put this object in some sort of a CLOSED state, and you can not requery info from this data source.

That's quite a typical mistake when you close a datasource, but intend to use it repeatedly further.

To avoid this, only call ***.close()** method on your datasource, when you do not need it anymore. For example, from your **Activity**'s **onDestroy()** method.

The answer is pretty much general, as you did not provide enough details on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your dialog is not doing dismiss thats way you are leaking the dialog.
You need to call dialog.dismiss() for dismiss the alert dialog.

```
if(dialog != null){
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```